# Passing data between windows / views

Tags: macos, nsview, nswindow

I have an overview window witch shows a list of customers.
On that screen is an button voor an new window for inserting new customers.
When i press on the save button the data get saved in an SQLite DB.
After that the inserted data has to be updated in my overview window.

How can i programmaly update that view from de insert window.

I've been looking on the internet and this website and can't find any info.

Answer (score 0):

When the data gets inserted, post a `NSNotification`.  Have the object that manages the visual customer list listen for the notification and refresh its view when it receives one.

Comment: From your description, it would be the "overview window" that would be doing the observing.

Comment: But how do i make the NSNotification then.
I don't understand how to connect it in my code.

If you have a small example it would be nice.

Comment: Something like `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kDataRecordSaved object:customer];` when you save the data.

Comment: Done some testing and it works great.

Now have an overview window en een sheet opens for the new customer.

Thanks to you all.

Should i post my solution here for other persons or not.